# Create Multidimensional Array From Table Text

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table

I am attempting to place text from a `<table>` into a an array, as an array of text.

Sample HTML:

```
<table class="sort">
    <caption>Census Data</caption>
    <tr>
        <th class="alpha">First Name:</th>
        <th class="alpha">Last Name:</th>
        <th class="date">Date of Birth:</th>
        <th class="numeric">Age:</th>
        <th class="alpha">Gender:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Parker</td>
        <td>12/23/1975</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>06/09/1982</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ultimate goal it to have an array like this:

```
var array = [
             ["Peter", "Parker", "12/23/1975", "36", "male"], 
             ["John", "Doe", "06/09/1982", "30", "male"]
            ];
```

This is what I currently have, my problem seems to be with me inner return not actually being an array when it reaches the outer map.  When I `alert(innerArray.toString());` it gives me the comma separated string as if it is a string inside, but on the outside it seems to `join` the arrays into one rather than make it multidimensional.

```
var outerArray = $(".sort tr").not(":first-child").map(function(){
    var innerArray = $(this).children().map(function(){
       return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();           
    return innerArray;
}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably some fancy way to do it with map, but I prefer just looping via `each` as it is easier to understand and maintain.

```
var resultArray = [];

$(".sort tr").not(":first-child").each(function () {
    var innerArray = [];

    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
        innerArray.push($(this).text());
    });

    resultArray.push(innerArray);
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/R8VAK/).

Comment: Fancy or not it works good sir!  Thank you kindly!  Think I got my head too wrapped around the `.map()` and `.toArray()` functions that I missed the obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var outerArray = new Array() ;

$('.sort').children('tr').each(function(i,elem) {
     outerArray.push(elem.children('td')) ;
});
```

Comment: I fixed some of the code errors in your answer to make it work, but it just places the jQuery Object of the element `<td>` into the array.  I need to be able to reference that data as a multidimensional array like: `var data = outerArray[0][2];`  Having it in element Object form doesn't really help.